# How find this limit $f'(0)$?

Tags: integration, limits

let $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}dt$$, Find the $f'(0)$

since
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\int_{0}^{x}\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}dt}{x}$$
since By Partial integration yields
$$\int_{0}^{x}\cos{\dfrac{1}{t}}dt=\int_{\frac{1}{x}}^{+\infty}\dfrac{\cos{u}}{u^2}du=-x^2\sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}+\int_{\frac{1}{x}}^{\infty}\dfrac{2\sin{u}}{u^3}du$$
so
$$\left|\dfrac{\int_{0}^{x}\cos{\frac{1}{t}}dt}{x}\right|\le|x|\left|\sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}\right|+\dfrac{1}{|x|}\int_{\frac{1}{x}}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{u^3}=|x|\left|\sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}\right|+|x|\to 0(x\to 0)$$

My Question: This problem have other methods?

Thank you

Comment: This is a nice approach.

Comment: You could L'Hopital's the end of line 2, which shows that the result is indeterminate.

Comment: How about using a series?

Comment: @waiwai933: I suggested that in my deleted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just integrate by parts in the integral directly:
$$f(x) = \int_0^x (-t^2){d \over dt} \bigg(\sin {1 \over t}\bigg)\,dt$$
$$=  -x^2\sin{1 \over x} + \int_0^{x} 2t\cos\bigg({1 \over t}\bigg)\,dt$$
(The limit as $x$ goes to zero of the boundary term is just zero.) The absolute value of $2t\cos\big({1 \over t}\big)$ is at most $2|t|$, so the second term is at most $x^2$. Hence $\big|{f(x) \over x}\big| \leq 2|x|$ and therefore the limit of the difference quotients is zero.

Of course this isn't that different from what you were doing, but you don't have to do any variable changes this way.

Comment: The integration by parts has a typo.  The integrand in the last line should be $2t\sin(1/t)$.