# If $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\cos\frac{1}{t}\ {dt}$, then caculate $f'(0)$

Tags: integration

> If $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\cos\frac{1}{t}\ {dt}$, then calculate $f'(0) $.

I found the answer [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609932/how-find-this-limit-f0) and understood its solution. But when I solve it myself, I first tried to solve it directly:

> $$f'(0)=\frac{\int_{0}^{x}\cos\frac{1}{x}dx}{x},$$
> And use the L'Hospital, I get $$f'(0)=\frac{\cos\frac{1}{x}}{1}$$ and get the conclusion that $f'(0)$ does not exist!

I do not know where is wrong, Could you point it out? Thank you!

Comment: L'Hopital is inconclusive when the resulting limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you! Got it.@BrianMoehring

Comment: The Hospital is overrated. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule . The condition that $\lim f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists is a sufficient condition for $\lim f(x)/g(x)$ to exist in the indeterminate case, but as you see from the article it is never asserted it's a necessary condition.

Comment: You should use Lebnitz rule

Comment: @user675453 And how on earth does Leibniz's rule apply here?

Comment: @Mark Viola, oh right... But it does give an expression for $f'(x)$ , which is not defined at 0. So is that the answer?

Comment: No it isn't the answer.  For $x\ne0$, $f'(x)=\cos(1/x)$.  And hence, $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ fails to exist.  BUT, $f'(0)=0$.  So, $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran: your answer is not complete and does not do anything to clear out the problem. You may need to review the statement of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be given by the integral

$$f(x)=\int_0^x \cos(1/t)\,dt$$

For $x\ne 0$, we see that $f'(x)=\cos(1/x)$.  Hence, $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ fails to exist.

---

But the fact that $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ does not exist, does *not* imply that $f'(0)$ does not exist.  In fact, we have

$$\begin{align}
f'(0)&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\int_0^x \cos(1/t)\,dt}x\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-x\sin(1/x)+\frac1x\int_0^x 2t\sin(1/t)\,dt\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-x\sin(1/x)+O(x)\right)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Hence, we see that $f(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$, but its derivative, $f'(x)$, is discontinuous at $0$.

---

The conditions to apply L'Hospital's Rule apply.  We have $f(x)=\int_0^x \cos(1/t)\,dt$ and $g(x)=x$ are differentiable on open interval's containing $0$.  But the limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(1/x)}{1}$$

does not exist.  Therefore, L'Hospital's Rule is a useless tool to determine $f'(0)$.

And that is all that is going on here.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes, I integrated by parts with $u=t^2$ and $v=-\sin(1/t)$.

Comment: @red_rose Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: I think one should consider $\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\int^x_\varepsilon\cos(t^{-1})\,dt$ before integration by parts as $\sin(t^{-1})$ is not of finite variation. After this (although I am still checking) your argument should carry over. $$
\begin{align}
\int^x_\varepsilon\cos(t^{-1})\,dt&=-\int^x_\varepsilon t^2 d\sin(t^{-1}) \\
&=-x^2\sin(x^{-1})+\varepsilon^2\sin(\varepsilon^{-1})+2\int^x_\varepsilon t\sin(t^{-1})\,dt\\
&\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\rightarrow0} -x^2\sin(x^{-1})+ 2\int^x_0 t\sin(t^{-1})\,dt\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Just one comment on your explanation of L'Hosital rule. In the present case, one condition of L'Hosital rule fails, that is the existence of the limit $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. Here is a version to clarify matters https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3727978/121671. That is the condition that an old professor of mine called the clairvoyant condition.

Comment: Thank you for your correction! About if the FOC's application, could I think as followings? As $\cos\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous over $(0,x]$ for every x($x\neq 0$), and whatever integrand when $x=0$(as it is a single point, so don't affect the definite integral), so $\cos\frac{1}{x}$ is definitely integrable over $[0,x]$, and when over $[\delta,x]$, the $\cos\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous so it has antiderivative, so for any $x\neq 0$, there is an antiderivative. So using the part two of the  FOC, the $f'(x)=\cos\frac{1}{x}$ when $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @red-rose Yes, you have it.  Well done.